# PHP Sessions data lost when changing directory?

Tags: php, session, directory

I've got a simple login system using PHP sessions, but just recently it seems that if you visit pages not in a certain directory (/login/) you will always be flagged as not logged in, even when you are. It seems that my session data is being lost when I change directories (say, to /login/user/).

I don't think I've touched the code myself since the problem appeared, is there something my web host could have done to my PHP installation that would delete the session data, and is there a workaround?

EDIT:
Inside each file that needs authorization, it loads a loginfunctions.php file which calls session_start() and checks the login. Files which work in /login and i copy and paste into /login/user stop working, even though i update all the relevant paths and links.

EDIT2:
Okay, some code.

In the actual pages that are giving me the error, this is the auth. code:

```
require_once("../../../includes/loginFunctions.php");

$login = new login; 
$login->checkLogin(0);
```

Inside loginFunctions.php is this:

```
class login{

    function checkLogin($requiredAccess){

            session_start();

            if($_SESSION['accesslevel'] < $requiredAccess || $_SESSION['logged_in'] != TRUE){
                die("You don't have access to this area. If you should have access, please log in again. <a href='/login/'>Login</a>");
            }

            if (isset($_SESSION['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])){
                if ($_SESSION['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] != md5($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])){
                    session_destroy();
                    die("Bad session. Please log in again. <a href='/login/'>Login</a> ");
                }
            } else {
                $_SESSION['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] = md5($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
            }

            if (!isset($_SESSION['initiated'])){
                session_regenerate_id();
                $_SESSION['initiated'] = true;
            }

    }

}
```

The $requiredAccess variable is the access level that you need to access this page, so if you have an accesslevel of 3 in the database you can view level 0, 1, 2 and 3 pages. This is specified when the function is called in the main page and is compared to the access level of the current user which is defined in $_SESSIONS when they log in.

I'm getting the error 'You don't have access to this area etc." when i try to access these pages. If i try to print the $_SESSION variables, nothing shows; they appear to be empty. However, if I move the file to the /login/ folder (one level up) and update the links, they work perfectly and all the variables print out fine. This makes me think the code is not the part that's not working, but some setting in my PHP install that has been changed without my notice.

Comment: Could you post the contents of the main site content for `/login/user/`? As in, `main.php`, `index.php`, or `default.php`. The problem may be as simple as not calling `session_start` at the top of the page. But more insight to the problem would yield more answers.

Comment: Inside each file that needs authorization, it loads a loginfunctions.php file which calls session_start() and checks the login. Files which work in /login and i copy and paste into /login/user stop working, even though i update all the relevant paths and links. Inside /login/user there are just 5 php files with random names (this is the backend of the site, it's not very pretty)

Answer (score 2):

maybe you aren't calling session_start() at the begging of pages not in /login/ ..?

Comment: Edited my first post to show how i'm calling that. Also, the same pages work if they're in the main /login/ directory.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem.
Check you don't have a php.ini file. Removing this sorted the problem out. Still looking ito exactly why. The php.ini file could even be blank and it would stop session data from  carrying over to more than one directory...

Comment: for clarification, a php.ini in your current directory. obviously you'll have a php.ini somewhere...

Comment: did you ever resolve this so that you can have a php.ini file in a directory? I have an issue where I need the php.ini for PEAR in a certain directory. However visiting that directory clears out the additional variables I store.

For instance $_SESSION['first_name'] is lost, but the session id is preserved.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that they changed the php.ini setting [session.cookie_path](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cookie-path).

You should call [session-set-cookie-params](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php) before you call `session_start` and make sure you set the cookie path yourself. Set it to the highest level directory you want the session to be valid for. EG if you set it to `/login` it will be valid for `/login` and `/login/user`. If you want your session to be valid for the etire site set the path to be `/`

Comment: I tried setting 

session_set_cookie_params(3600, "/");

to no avail. Also, I checked session.cookie_path in my php info and it's set to "/" anyway.

Comment: Hmmm. Not sure what the issue could be. Please edit your question and post some code.

Comment: Updated my post for you. Thanks for taking the time to reply.

Comment: When you log in do you se a cookie set? If so, is the domain and path correct? You can check for cookies in FireFox under "Tools >Page Info", on the "Security" tab

Answer (score 0):

i had a similar issue. you may want to use:
 `<? 
setcookie("TestCookie", $value, time()+3600, "/~rasmus/", ".example.com", 1); ?>`

or something similar. i know cookie and session variables are a different desired solution, but this was able to clear up my issue.

[See here for documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the same `php.ini` file in each directory that you want to access the session variables from.

Answer (score -1):

This is why you shouldn't use directory to make false friendly URLs...

Don't forget to call session_start() every time you need the session.

Comment: What does "use directory to make false friendly URLs" have anything to do with this? I have "friendly URLs" in almost every system I build and have never had an issue. And hey, ever noticed StackOverflow.com does, too?

Comment: I think he means that most friendly URLs are made by rewriting rather than by actual directories on disk.

Comment: @erisco: Ah. Thanks for clarifying. That makes sense. But still, whether rewritten or not the issue would still occur -- the browser has no idea that rewriting is occurring and cookie paths (if that's the issue) must still be set correctly.

Comment: there's no rewriting going on with these URLs in question. see comment to original post for how i'm calling session_start().

Comment: also, how would you suggest I organise the files? Maintenance would be a nightmare if they were all piled in the same directory..?